# Correct posture while sitting seiza for spinal alignment

Tags: meditation-posture

While sitting seiza, should most of your weight fall on your butt, hips, or coccyx (base of spine)?

I have read that you should try to sit really straight or even to lean back to prevent spinal load.

I personally sit with a seiza bench.

Comment: This isn't really a question about Buddhism; it would do better on a physiology site. Energetically you want to keep your head-top suspended, and your weight dropping vertically from the head-top through the dontien into the floor.  If you focus on outer posture you'll get stiff; try to feel the energetic alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your experience level.
For beginners, best to focus on generally keeping body straight, but staying relaxed and keeping it sustainable for long sits. People tend to have problems and deformities, don't force it into what you imagine a correct perfect straight posture is. Just have the intention to be straight, relaxed comfortable, let the body slowly correct itself over the years (doing yoga, other kinds of therapy to address problems with posture outside the meditation sit).

For intermediate, this article dealing with spinal alignment specifics will help:
https://notesonthedhamma.blogspot.com/2019/07/04-ujum-kayam-panidhaya-maintaining.html

For advanced, there's what I call the Jazzy effect:
https://lucid24.org/tped/j/jasi/index.html